# Variable of object set in construct is out of scope in destruct

Tags: php, oop, scope

So, I started writing a bootstrap script for a micro framework I'm working on for learning purposes (both learn more about programming, php and oop) and I came across this weird unexpected behavior.

The variable $config which starts a new object of Config() class is being called in Bootstrap's __construct which is public, then it is being used in Bootstrap's __destruct which is also public. The variable itself of $config is public and declared before __construct as you can see below.

Now, what's weird is that I get a notice and fatal error from using $config in __destruct, it says the variable doesn't exist and the fatal error is calling a member function on a non object (because $config doesn't exist)

Here is the script, hope someone could point out why this weird behavior happens, it is possible that I'm missing something and the behavior makes sense but well, I'm missing it then please point it out.

```js
<?php
basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) == "bootstrap.php" ? die("No direct script access allowed") : '';


class Bootstrap
{


  public $config;

  protected $start_route;



  public function __construct()
  {
   $this->settings();
   $config = new Config();
   $this->database();
   $this->routing();
   $start_route = new Route($config);
   $start_route->initiate();
  }


  public function run()
  {

   $db_info = new DatabaseInfo();

   $database = new Database([
    'database_type'    => $db_info->get_db('dbdriver'),
    'database_name'    => $db_info->get_db('database'),
    'server'           => $db_info->get_db('hostname'),
    'username'         => $db_info->get_db('username'),
    'password'         => $db_info->get_db('password'),
    'charset'          => $db_info->get_db('dbcharset'),

    'port'             => $db_info->get_db('port'),
    'prefix'           => $db_info->get_db('dbprefix'),
 
    // driver_option for connection, read more from
    // http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php
    'option'           => [
     PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL
    ]
   ]);

   /*
    *
    * Read is much faster than Write,
    * while INSERT will increase load time by ~40ms per each query,
    * COUNT will only increase by ~2ms
    *
    */
   $count = $database->count('site_log', [
    'log_type' => 1
   ]);
/*
   $database->insert('site_log', [
    'remote_addr' => '127.0.0.1',
    'request_uri' => '/',
    'log_type'    => 1,
    'message'     => 'Test Query'
   ]);
*/
   echo 'The are ' . $count . ' rows in log with severity level of 1!<br />';

  }


  // Since it's being called from __constrcut, it will run before run()
  private function settings()
  {

   require BOOTPATH.'core\\config'.CLASSFIX.EXT;

  }


  // Since it's being called from __constrcut, it will run before run()
  private function database()
  {

   require BOOTPATH.'core\\database'.CLASSFIX.EXT;
   return;

  }


  // Since it's being called from __constrcut, it will run before run()
  private function routing()
  {

   require BOOTPATH.'core\\router'.CLASSFIX.EXT;
   return;

  }


  // Since it's being outputed within __destrcut, it will run after run() and basically last
  public function __destruct()
  {

   $script_end = (float) array_sum( explode( ' ',microtime() ) );

   echo 'Welcome to ' . $config->get_conf('site_name') . '<br />';
   echo 'Processing time: '. sprintf( '%.4f', ( $script_end - APP_START ) ).' seconds';

  }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$config = new Config();
```

you are creating a new `$config` object in the scope of the constructor, you are not populating the `$config` property of the `Bootstrap` class

You have to use `$this->config`; to access the class property

Comment: I'm not sure why. $this->settings(); calls the function that includes the class file of Config. Then $config is set to new Config(); and is supposed to be widely available within the bootstrap class as it is declared as public and is assigned an object in the constructor.

Comment: No, the scope of the variable `$config` is only within the constructor, not the wide class. You are talking about `$this->config` This is the public property of the class

Comment: It works, thank you! :)
I guess I misunderstood some concepts of oop.

Comment: the fact is that to access the class property in PHP you have to prefix it with `$this`, while in other programming languages you can avoid the `$this` prefix

Comment: I understand, thank you for your help, I appreciate it.